# How to generate heat map on the Whole Slide Images (.svs format) using some probability values?

Tags: python-3.x, matlab, heatmap, openslide

I am trying to generate heat map, or probability map, for Whole Slide Images (WSIs) using probability values. I have coordinate points (which determine areas on the WSIs) and corresponding probability values.

**Basic Introduction on WSI:** WSIs are large is size (almost 100000 x 100000 pixels). Hence, can't open these images using normal image viewer. The WSIs are processed using **OpenSlide software**.

I have seen previous posts in Stack Overflow on related to heat map, but as WSIs are processed in a different way, I am unable to figure out how to apply these solutions. Some examples that I followed: [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55317339/how-to-create-heatmap-over-an-image-using-coordinate-points), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53349947/extract-a-whole-scale-image-from-a-svs-format-file-in-c), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6524886/image-overlay-with-matrix/6525813#6525813), [4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53242599/convert-image-array-to-original-svs-format), [5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55359745/image-registration-for-whole-slide-digital-pathology-images), [6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16415957/heat-map-image-with-discrete-values), [7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34912362/how-to-create-a-heat-map-matrix-and-generate-regions-based-heat-in-python), [8](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54394607/how-to-generate-a-probability-distribution-on-an-image), [9](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46020894/how-to-superimpose-heatmap-on-a-base-image), [10](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2369492/generate-a-heatmap-in-matplotlib-using-a-scatter-data-set), [11](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42481203/heatmap-on-top-of-image), etc.

Comment: Have you tried reading in the image in tiles, creating the heat map for each tile independently, and saving the tiles back to file?

Comment: @CrisLuengo Yes, I can create heat map for each tile independently. But I don't have idea how can I stitch all the tiles together or, saving the tiles back to file.  Please suggest.

Comment: I was going to suggest you write a tiled TIFF file out, which is not too complicated, but you are likely best off using the vips library. It has a Python binding: https://jcupitt.github.io/libvips/2017/09/01/libvips-for-Python.html — I don’t know how to use it, so won’t write a full answer, but I’m sure you can figure it out, I hear it’s easy to use.

Comment: Yes, I know. but I am looking for a specific answer. Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To generate heat map on WSIs, follow below instructions:

**First of all Extract image patches and save the coordinates. Use below code for patch extraction.** The code require some changes as per the requirements. The code has been copied from: [patch extraction code link](https://github.com/Steven-N-Hart/WSI-Classification/blob/master/scripts/patch_extraction.py)

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
from __future__ import division
from __future__ import print_function

import argparse
import logging
try:
    import Image
except:
    from PIL import Image
import math
import numpy as np
import openslide
import os
from time import strftime,gmtime

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Extract a series of patches from a whole slide image')
parser.add_argument("-i", "--image", dest='wsi',  nargs='+', required=True, help="path to a whole slide image")
parser.add_argument("-p", "--patch_size", dest='patch_size', default=299, type=int, help="pixel width and height for patches")
parser.add_argument("-b", "--grey_limit", dest='grey_limit', default=0.8, type=float, help="greyscale value to determine if there is sufficient tissue present [default: `0.8`]")
parser.add_argument("-o", "--output", dest='output_name', default="output", help="Name of the output file directory [default: `output/`]")

parser.add_argument("-v", "--verbose",
            dest="logLevel",
            choices=['DEBUG', 'INFO', 'WARNING', 'ERROR', 'CRITICAL'],
            default="INFO",
            help="Set the logging level")
args = parser.parse_args()

if args.logLevel:
        logging.basicConfig(level=getattr(logging, args.logLevel))

wsi=' '.join(args.wsi)


""" Set global variables """
mean_grey_values = args.grey_limit * 255
number_of_useful_regions = 0
wsi=os.path.abspath(wsi)
outname=os.path.abspath(args.output_name)
basename = os.path.basename(wsi)
level = 0

def main():
    img,num_x_patches,num_y_patches = open_slide()
    logging.debug('img: {}, num_x_patches = {}, num_y_patches: {}'.format(img,num_x_patches,num_y_patches))

    for x in range(num_x_patches):
        for y in range(num_y_patches):
            img_data = img.read_region((x*args.patch_size,y*args.patch_size),level, (args.patch_size, args.patch_size))
            print_pics(x*args.patch_size,y*args.patch_size,img_data,img)

    pc_uninformative = number_of_useful_regions/(num_x_patches*num_y_patches)*100
    pc_uninformative = round(pc_uninformative,2)
    logging.info('Completed patch extraction of {} images.'.format(number_of_useful_regions))
    logging.info('{}% of the image is uninformative\n'.format(pc_uninformative))


def print_pics(x_top_left,y_top_left,img_data,img):
    if x_top_left % 100 == 0 and y_top_left % 100 == 0 and x_top_left != 0:
        pc_complete = round(x_top_left /img.level_dimensions[0][0],2) * 100
        logging.info('{:.2f}% Complete at {}'.format(pc_complete,strftime("%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S +0000", gmtime())))
        exit()

    img_data_np = np.array(img_data)
    """ Convert to grayscale"""
    grey_img = rgb2gray(img_data_np)
    if np.mean(grey_img) < mean_grey_values:
        logging.debug('Image grayscale = {} compared to threshold {}'.format(np.mean(grey_img),mean_grey_values))
        global number_of_useful_regions
        number_of_useful_regions += 1
                wsi_base = os.path.basename(wsi)
                wsi_base = wsi_base.split('.')[0]
        img_name = wsi_base + "_" + str(x_top_left) + "_" + str(y_top_left) + "_" + str(args.patch_size)
        #write_img_rotations(img_data_np,img_name)
                logging.debug('Saving {} {} {}'.format(x_top_left,y_top_left,np.mean(grey_img)))
        save_image(img_data_np,1,img_name)

def gen_x_and_y(xlist,ylist,img):
    for x in xlist:
        for y in ylist:
            img_data = img.read_region((x*args.patch_size,y*args.patch_size),level, (args.patch_size, args.patch_size))
            yield (x, y,img_data)

def open_slide():
    """
    The first level is always the main image
    Get width and height tuple for the first level
    """

    logging.debug('img: {}'.format(wsi))

    img = openslide.OpenSlide(wsi)
    img_dim = img.level_dimensions[0]

    """
    Determine what the patch size should be, and how many iterations it will take to get through the WSI
    """
    num_x_patches = int(math.floor(img_dim[0] / args.patch_size))
    num_y_patches = int(math.floor(img_dim[1] / args.patch_size))

    remainder_x = img_dim[0] % num_x_patches
    remainder_y = img_dim[1] % num_y_patches

    logging.debug('The WSI shape is {}'.format(img_dim))
    logging.debug('There are {} x-patches and {} y-patches to iterate through'.format(num_x_patches,num_y_patches))
    return img,num_x_patches,num_y_patches

def validate_dir_exists():
    if os.path.isdir(outname) == False:
        os.mkdir(outname)
    logging.debug('Validated {} directory exists'.format(outname))
    if os.path.exists(wsi):
        logging.debug('Found the file {}'.format(wsi))
    else:
        logging.debug('Could not find the file {}'.format(wsi))
        exit()

def rgb2gray(rgb):
    """Converts an RGB image into grayscale """
    r, g, b = rgb[:,:,0], rgb[:,:,1], rgb[:,:,2]
    gray = 0.2989 * r + 0.5870 * g + 0.1140 * b
    return gray

def save_image(img,j,img_name):
        tmp = os.path.join(outname,img_name+"_"+str(j)+".png")
    try:
        im = Image.fromarray(img)
        im.save(tmp)
    except:
        print('Could not print {}'.format(tmp))
                exit()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    validate_dir_exists()
    main()
```

**Secondly, generate the probability values of each patches.**
**Finally, replace all the pixel values within a coordinates with the corresponding probability values and display the results using color maps.**

This is the basic idea of generating heat map on WSIs. You can modify the code and concept to get a heat map as per your wish.

Answer (score 1):

We have developed a python package for processing whole-slide-images:
https://github.com/amirakbarnejad/PyDmed
Here is a tutorial for getting heatmaps for whole-slide-images:
https://amirakbarnejad.github.io/Tutorial/tutorial_section5.html.
Also here is a sample notebook that gets heatmaps for WSIs using PyDmed:
[Link to the sample notebook.](https://github.com/amirakbarnejad/PyDmed/blob/8082a02da20c2b5285c722df31326e56ac08f56d/sample_notebooks/Sample3_Heatmap_for_WSIs/sample3_heatmap_for_WSIs.ipynb)

The benefit of PyDmed is that it is multi-processed. The dataloader sends a stream of patches to GPU(s), and the StreamWriter writes to disk in a separate process. Therefore, it is highly efficient. The running time of course depends on the machine, the size of WSIs, etc. On a good machine with a good GPU, PyDmed can generate heatmaps for ~120 WSIs in one day.